# How to stop MacOS caching folder contents

Tags: finder, big-sur

I am using Big Sur 11.6.1 (20G224)

I spend a lot of my time downloading client files from the web to then work on locally - the issue is that I can download a file but then, in Finder, the file does not show sometimes for a few hours.

Example, I go to Safari and download a file to a folder - I can confirm the file is there as if I try to download it again (a) I see it in the folder list and (b) it will prompt me to say it is there and do I want to overwrite it etc

However, if I then go to Photoshop, for example, and click open or even just go to Finder and try and open the file - it is not listed. The prior files show but not the one/s I have just downloaded. I have tried closing the folder and opening again, changing from list to icon view etc to no avail.

An hour or some random time later the file will then 'appear' - is there any way I can stop MacOS from what I assume is caching folder contents so the file appears real time?

Comment: That's nothing 'intentionally' cached. It should be instantaneous. How busy is the Mac, how much RAM is in use at these times & how full is your drive? [& do you have your Photoshop scratch on a separate, fast drive?]

Comment: There is around 50% free disk space, memory usage is low -  have Photoshop on the same drive but even if I go into Finder it does not show for some time. Latest example was a file which now shows with a created time of 13.01 which did not show until 14.53

Comment: Check what happens if you restart the Finder [Opt/Right-click it in the Dock, Relaunch] This kind of thing used to happen way back in maybe Mavericks, but I've not seen it since then.

Comment: I'd agree: it should be instant. Is this a mechanical drive or an SSD? I'd verify the disk to start with. I'd also check whether you get the same behaviour in a new user account. If not, then that might suggest some corrupt Finder prefs, or possibly some third-party app that's conflicting. DefaultFoldersX ? Also, does this happen in non-Adobe apps, or not?

Comment: It even happens in Finder - the app itself does not seem to matter. I have tried reboots as restarting Finder before to no avail. It is totally random - it might be 5 mins today then 2 hours tomorrow.